# Mongo DB aggregation with array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My collection schema is as follows:

**Product**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(), // default mongo db id
  specification: [
    {key: 'Name', value: "value 1"},
    {key: 'Category', value: "value 2"},
    {key: 'Department', value: "value 3"}
  ]
}
```

Now I want to query on this with a generic filter. For example,

1. Get me all product with `Name = value 1` and `Category in [value 2, value 3]` and `Department = value 3`
2. Get me all product with `Name = value 1` or `Category = value 2` or `Department in [value 3, value 4]`

I have been trying to use `$match` with `$elemMatch`. But that only allows only one query but I am not able to use the `$and` and `$or` operator.

Comment: so you want two queries? 

one for Get me all product with Name = value 1 and Category in [value 2, value 3] and Department = value 3 

And other for Get me all product with Name = value 1 or Category = value 2 or Department in [value 3, value 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch` just fine, you just have to put `$and` / `$or` at the top level.

Your first example would be

```js
db.products.find({
  $and: [
    { 
      specification: {
        $elemMatch: { key: 'Name', value: 'value 1' }
      }
    },
    {
      specification: {
        $elemMatch: { key: 'Category', value: { $in: ['value 1', 'value 2'] } }
      }
    },
    { 
      specification: {
        $elemMatch: { key: 'Department', value: 'value 3' }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```