# MongoDB aggregation match criteria to find if a field exists with value in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
   "attributes" : [
                    {
                      "dept" : "accounts",
                      "location" : "onshore"
                    },
                    {
                      "dept" : "HR",
                      "location" : "offshore"
                    },
                    {
                      "dept" : "technology"
                      "location": "NL"
                    } 
                 ]
},
{
   "attributes" : [
                    {
                      "dept" : "accounts",
                      "location" : "onshore"
                    },
                    {
                      "dept" : "technology"
                      "location": "London"
                    } 
                 ]
},
{
   "attributes" : [
                    {
                      "dept" : "accounts",
                      "location" : "onshore"
                    },
                    {
                      "dept" : "HR"
                      "location": "London"
                    } 
                 ]
}
```

I want to get those documents where `attributes` array has `dept` :`technology` with `location` **NOT**equal to `london` or the `attributes` array does not have field `dept` :`technology`. So the final output will be like below:

```
{
   "attributes" : [
                    {
                      "dept" : "accounts",
                      "location" : "onshore"
                    },
                    {
                      "dept" : "HR",
                      "location" : "offshore"
                    },
                    {
                      "dept" : "technology"
                      "location": "NL"
                    } 
                 ]
},
{
   "attributes" : [
                    {
                      "dept" : "accounts",
                      "location" : "onshore"
                    },
                    {
                      "dept" : "HR"
                      "location": "London"
                    } 
                 ]
}
```

I have tried this solution but it gives me all the documents:

```
{
                                "attributes": {
                                    "$elemMatch": {
                                        "$or": [
                                            {
                                                "dept": {
                                                    "$nin": ["technology"]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "$and": [
                                                    {
                                                        "dept": "technology"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "location": {"$ne" : "London"}
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: You need to wrap $elemMatch with `$and` / `$or` not the other way around. This recent question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614866/mongo-db-aggregation-with-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$elemMatch` evaluates each item of the array, we cannot use `$nin` or `$ne` operators if the condition is only to negate the boolean expression.

Instead, we should use the [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) to performs a logical **NOT** operation on the specified *< operator-expression >*.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        $not: {
          "$elemMatch": {
            dept: "technology"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          dept: "technology",
          location: {
            $ne: "London"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QghizRV3aSI)